# more elements in the method signature (2) than in the generic signature (1) for function ‘asJSON’ with plot_ly in R

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I'm trying to plot a chart with plotly in R but I receive a strange error and I have no idea what to check, it worked with one computer but I'm trying to do with the other one and the error comes up:

> Error in matchSignature(signature, fdef) : more elements in the method signature (2) than in the generic signature (1) for function ‘asJSON’

Here is my code:

```r
  title_style = list(
    size = 18, 
    color = "#7f7f7f", 
    family = "Courier New, monospace"
  )
  
  trace1 <<- list(type = "heatmap", x = labels, y = labels, z = cm)
  
  data <- list(trace1)
    
  conf_plot <<- plot_ly(colors = colorRamp(c("white", "darkblue")))
  conf_plot <- add_trace(conf_plot, type=trace1$type, x=trace1$x, y=trace1$y, z=trace1$z)
  print(conf_plot)
```

Values of `labels`:

`"Venda forte"  "Venda fraca"  "Compra fraca" "Compra forte"`

Values of `cm`:

```
       -2   -1    1    2
  -2 0.14 0.00 0.01 0.06
  -1 0.08 0.00 0.01 0.08
  1  0.08 0.00 0.00 0.07
  2  0.08 0.00 0.01 0.37
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by wrapping the `cm` matrix like so:

```r
matrix(cm, nrow=4, ncol=4)
```

It just removes the col names and row names.